# How to make an efficient Count of rows from another table (join)

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a database of 100,000 names in cemeteries.  The cemeteries number around 6000....i wish to return the number of names in each cemetery..

If i do an individual query, it takes a millisecond

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblnames
    WHERE tblcemetery_ID = 2
```

My actual query goes on and on and I end up killing it so I dont kill our database.  Can someone point me at a more efficient method?

```
select tblcemetery.id,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblnames
        WHERE tblcemetery_ID = tblcemetery.id) AS casualtyCount
    from tblcemetery                                                      
      ORDER BY
   fldcemetery
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing an explain, but if I had to hazard a guess, I would say to insure that the two fields you are using to join in your subquery are indexed.

Comment: Yes, sorry, in each cemetery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rephrase your query to use a join instead of a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    COUNT(t2.tblcemetery_ID) AS casualtyCount
FROM tblcemetery t1
LEFT JOIN tblnames t2
    ON t1.id = t2.tblcemetery_ID
GROUP BY
    t1.id
ORDER BY
    t1.id
```

I have heard that in certain databases, such as Oracle, the optimizer is smart enough to figure out what I wrote above, and would refactor your query under the hood.  But the MySQL optimizer might not be smart enough to do this.

One nice side effect of this refactor is that we now see an opportunity to improve performance even more, by adding indices to the join columns.  I am assuming that `id` is the primary key of `tblcemetery`, in which case it is already indexed.  But you could add an index to `tblcemetery_ID` in the `tblnames` table for a possible performance boost:

```
CREATE INDEX cmtry_idx ON tblnames (tblcemetery_ID)
```

Comment: This implies that you anticipate that there's a cemetry with no one buried in it.

Comment: @Strawberry A lot of people in the US use mortuaries and cemeteries as income tax scams.  It wouldn't surprise me if there are a few cemeteries out there which don't actually have dead people in them.

Comment: ...or pet cemeteries I suppose.

Comment: I added the index and the query worked in 0.219sec!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Or you could look up `group by` [here f.e.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and do something like

```
   SELECT tblcemetery_ID,  sum(1) from tblnames group by tblscemetery_id
```

You essentially sum up 1 for each name entry that belongs to this cemetery as you are not interessted in the names at all, no need to join to the cemetary detail table

Not sure if `sum(1)` or `count(*)` is better, both should work.

Youll only get cemetaries that have ppl inside though

Answer (score 0):

It could even be done without a `JOIN` by using an `EXISTS` clause like this

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS casualtyCount
FROM tblcemetery
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblnames WHERE tblcemetery_ID=id)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```